# VBA- picking one cell for each column that contain certain text in a Matrix with the max number of rows selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a matrix of information that let user to input task they are willing to do. User have 3 choices:

A. I want to do this.
B. I do not mind doing this. and
C. I do not want to do this.

after I collect user data, I'd like to assign each task to each person base on their will (pick A over B) (pair up one task - one person). Are there any advice on how I can  do it?

note:

- column labels are user name and rows are tasks.
- Obviously there are some task no one are willing to do and it is ok to leave it blank. (the number of task are expected to be greater than number of user, so some task will be blank anyhow)
- I do not need all possible solution, just 1 solution will do

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need VBA to solve this. Assign values for "A.", "B.", "C." and blank cells, then look for the max and use a vlookup for finding the person; if given person is found then use an alternate sequence.
I would create an index for overall willingness (sum of assigned values) per person to make the values more unique. 
If you would intend to make a macro I would start with the lowest willingness tasks and look for the highest value from people who are not yet assigned, if there are more than one of these people then I would give the job to the lowest overall willingness person (since he'll be harder to assign to other tasks).
P.S. the smiley doesn't make up for your lack of willingness to work. :(

Comment: thanks for the input, the trouble i face is that i have over 100 rows and columns, and it is very likely that there are over 1 person that are willing to do a specific task. And since each person can only perform 1 task, I would need a more sudoku-style solve (using macros to find out which task best suits that person, so the max number of tasks will be performed). My struggle is on how to apply such looping as brute force loop will be too tedious for such datasize.

Comment: I would like to see you at least try, give a sample of the table setup and specify what you would like to have in the end. I gave you help with the last one.